# Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException when I try to access Model in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have problems in a typical place.
When I access to Model or any dynamic variables (through ViewBag) in View,
I get Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException.

Example
View (View/Assignments/Assignments.cshtml):

```
@using DocMaster.Models
@model List<IGrouping<string, User>>
...
<ul class="tree">
  @foreach (var dep in Model)
  {
    <li class="close" name='open_close'>
      <span class="org">@dep</span>
      <ul>
        @foreach (var user in dep)
        {
          <li class="li_user" name="resp_add" id="@user.Id">
            <span class="user">@user.Surname @user.Name @user.Patronymic</span>
          </li>
        }
      </ul>
   </li>
  }
</ul>
```

Controller (Controllers/AssignmentController.cs):

```
public class AssignmentController : Controller
{
    private  PgDb db = new PgDb();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Assignments(Guid docId)
    {
        var departments = db.Users.OrderBy(x => x.Surname).GroupBy(x => x.Department.Name).ToList();

        return View(departments);
    }
}
```

StackTrace

```
Строка 76:                         <div class="dn" id="user_book03">
Строка 77:                             <ul class="tree">
Строка 78:                                 @foreach (var dep in Model)
Строка 79:                                 {
Строка 80:                                     <li class="close" name='open_close'>

Исходный файл: C:\Users\ruslan\source\repos\Documentics\DocMaster\Views\Assignment\Assignments.cshtml    Строка: 78 

Трассировка стека: 


[RuntimeBinderException: Не удается выполнить привязки исполняющей среды по нулевой ссылке]
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object ) +115
   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1(CallSite site, T0 arg0) +629
   ASP._Page_Views_Assignment_Assignments_cshtml.Execute() in C:\Users\ruslan\source\repos\Documentics\DocMaster\Views\Assignment\Assignments.cshtml:78
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that

```
        var departments = db.Users.OrderBy(x => x.Surname).GroupBy(x => x.Department.Name).ToList();
```

is returning a value because the error is insisting that you have a null reference somewhere in the code and I'm assuming that's where it is with the code giving. Debug the controller method and find out where the null reference is.